# How to disable tab completion in the python shell?

Tags: python, shell, autocomplete

Whenever I press tab in the python shell to create an indented block, I get the message

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
Display all 186 possibilities? (y or n)`
```

which prevents me from properly indenting anything. I'm not sure how I enabled tab completion in the shell.
I found [this blog post](http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.com/2009/09/tab-completion-in-python-shell-how-to.html) detailing how to enable tab completion by creating a .pyrc file and sourcing it in your .bashrc. Looking through my .zshrc, I can't find anything that sources any such file.

I'm using Mac OS X.

Comment: Are you using zsh? or bash?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file on your home directory called `.pyrc` with following content:

```
import readline  
readline.parse_and_bind("set disable-completion on")  
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: self-insert")
```

Then open python shell with

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pyrc python
```